# Stop Looping the content in jQuery

Tags: jquery

On http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/index.html in the Hand Strength. I was trying to figure out how to stop the looping the content once I clicked one of the list items. I just want to display the content once clicked on the list items. Currently when one of the list items is clicked and it displays the content and wait few seconds, the content rotates the next content without clicking item.

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#featured").tabs({fx:{opacity: "toggle"}}).tabs("rotate", 5000, true);
});
```

Comment: Look here: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) http://www.elitedeafpoker.com/dev/js/rotate1.js
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'on'

Comment: Please extract the SMALLEST portion of actual code that produces your error, and then post that with appropriate markup.  You are not likely to get many quality answers just posting a link. - be sure to include reference to any plugin you might be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$("element").click(function(){
    $("#featured").stop();
});
```

From http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Not sure of the element name, as the site is block by corporate firewall.

Comment: Ok, actually I removed the .tabs("rotate", 5000, true); and it worked just fine - thank you very much!